# Apache"AuthType form" authentication Nginx alternative

Tags: php, nginx

We're currently migrating from Apache to Nginx. This all went surprisingly well, except migrating our restricted project environment.

In Apache we had a custom login form that replaces the basic http authentication. We achieved this by using the `AuthType form` and `AuthFormProvider dbd`. By default Nginx doesn't support this. It tried using the `auth_request` module without any luck.

**What i'm trying to achieve:**
A virtual host that is protected by a custom login form. On post it should do a lookup in a mysql database to verify the username password and group.

**my current setup:**

```
server{
    listen *:8081;

    location /auth {

        include fcgi.conf;
        ....

        alias /var/*******/htdocs/auth/auth.php;
     }
}

server {
    listen *:80;

    server_name ~^(?<sname>.+?).projects.#######.com$ ~^(?<sname>.+?).projects.migrate.#######.com$;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/projects#######com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/projects#######com.error.log;

    root /var/*******/htdocs/$sname/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    error_page 401 = /login;
    error_page 404 = /404.html;

    location /login {
        auth_request off;
        ....

        alias /var/*******/htdocs/auth/login.php;
    }

    location /auth{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;

        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Auth-Key "**************";
    }

    location /404.html{
        alias /var/*******/htdocs/auth/404.html;
    }

    location / {
        auth_request /auth;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        ....
    }
}
```

The problem i'm facing right now it that i can't get the `POST` vars, posted by the login from.

**UPDATE:**

Basicly the problem is the redirect to a 401. During this proces `POST` data is prohibit.

> When automatically redirecting a POST request after receiving a 301
>   status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents will erroneously
>   change it into a GET request.

The only way to get this working is tricking nginx, so i will process the post data.

Comment: As far as I understand what `AuthType form` is, you'll have to implement it yourself in PHP (or anything else).

Comment: With AuthType for you have the option to design the Authorization window yourself. Instead of the basic version

Comment: Docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html